# Attach a class method to window object using decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I am using VueJS with typescrpit but this could be in any js framework.

I have componenets with some methods I want to expose globally so they can be used via the browser console. First idea is to attach them to the window object. This could be done from a lifecycle method such us mounted in my case, but I prefered a cleaner easier solution to write and to use, using decorators.

I've tried something like:

mycomponenet.ts :

```
function makeGlobal() {
   return function(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
     (window as any)[propertyKey] = () => target[propertyKey]();
   };
 }
```

Then this decorator will be used easily like :

```
@makeGlobal()
myMethodToGoGloabl(){
// do stuff ...
}
```

Till now everything works fine, until the function uses `"this"` like :

```
@makeGlobal()
myMethodToGoGloabl(){
  this.firstName = "";
}
```

Then I get a error firstName of undefined. I understood by searching and reading that the decorator is executed before class instantiation, therefor what I exposed (correct me if I m mistaken) is a prototype method and not a method of the instance that why we have no access to this. I've tried to bind(this) but I failed for the same reason that I don't expose globally the method of the instance.

Is there a way to use decorators in my case or they are useless here?

Comment: So you want every global method to keep alive the instance of the function?

Comment: Maybe this can be done in Vue but not in other frameworks, since Vue provides some hook to modify the component instance properties

Comment: It should work as expected, by reading your code. Please create a working sample online then we could figure out the exact reason.

Comment: I believe that that is a bad idea to use decorators. You have to make sure that your property name is only one and also you might have some problems with garbage collectors as soon as your component dies. But if it is a singleton and it will leave forever then it is possible to do.

Answer (score -1):

Guess the issue is your decorator. You do not take over the this instance at all...
Also the way you do it, you won't be able to pass parameters.

Suggestion:

```
function makeGlobal() {
   return function(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
     var currentThis = this;
     (window as any)[propertyKey] = () => target[propertyKey].apply(currentThis, args);
   };
 }
```

Also keep in mind what Christian says in the comment. It basically can only work for singletons, as it will override the method for multiple instances

Comment: I don't see how this solution can work, currentThis does not refer to the component instance

Comment: You don't need to actually bind 'this' to the instance method since it's already there.